# What is the growth rate of the logarithm of the factorial sequence?

Tags: computational-complexity, factorial

I'd like to know the space complexity of storing bit string representations of the numbers in the factorial sequence (as in a memoized factorial function).  So each number $f_i=i!$ in $i=0 \cdots n$ takes $\log_2 f_i$ bits, but how fast does that grow with $i$?  Even better would be to know the sum of that sequence or (more reasonably) what a good bound is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need [Stirling's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n! = \prod_{i=1}^{n} i \leq \prod_{i=1}^{n} n = n^{n}$. So $log(n!) \leq log(n^{n}) = n log(n)$. And so $log(n!) = O(n log(n))$.

Answer (score 2):

As for asymptotic bounds, note $\log n! \in \Theta(n \log n)$. This is immediate from $n^n \geq n! \geq (n/2)^{n/2}$.